# Как правильно подключить postgresql к cakephp?

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

Как правильно подключить postgresql к cakephp?

Comment: в конфиге `config\app.php` настраиваете свой датасорс `Datasources.YourConnectionName` указывая `'driver' => Postgres::class`. В противном случае, суть вопроса не ясна

Comment: можете оформить как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP поддерживает Postresql "из коробки". Настройки подключений располагаются в файле конфигурации `config\app.php`.
В секции `Datasources` конфига перечислены настроенные подключения (обычно там `default` и `test`). Редактируйте эти подключения или добавляете новые по аналогии, указав при этом значение поля `driver` как `Postgres::class` подключив его в `uses \Cake\Database\Driver\Postgres`

Если вы добавляете дополнительный источник, то затем для его использования вы либо конфигурируете модели данных, указывая названия этого коннекта (параметром `cake bake model ...`), либо обращаетесь к нему через `ConnectionManager::get('...')`.